# How to parse SBT test reports on Shippable?

Tags: scala, junit, continuous-integration, sbt, shippable-ci

I have a simple *Scala* project, build with `sbt`, tested with JUnit. The project is plugged into *Shippable CI* and in the CI interface, I can see `Tests` tab when running a build. Seeing `"No test reports exist, skipping test report processing"` message and reading Shippable documentation led to adding following into the `shippable.yml` file:

```
before_script:
    - mkdir -p shippable/testresults
    - ln -s ../target/test-reports shippable/testresults
```

Shippable now recognises that the are some files - they look like regular JUnit XML test output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<testsuite hostname="Davids-MacBook-Pro.local" name="recfun.PascalSuite" tests="3" errors="0" failures="0" time="0.027">
    <properties>
        <property name="jline.esc.timeout" value="0"/>
        <property name="java.runtime.name" value="Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment"/>
....
```

, but I get following error from Shippable and test results are not provided:

```
reports --destination /shippableci/testresults tests --source /root/src/bitbucket.org/gaincore/recfun/shippable/testresults
No valid test reports found in path: /root/src/bitbucket.org/gaincore/recfun/shippable/testresults exiting...
```

What do I have wrong? Do I need to do anything else with the `xml` output? Does it need to be parsed, or are the any naming conventions?

Answer (score 2):

Its working fine for me. This is the build link: https://app.shippable.com/runs/56ebcfb56b2b030d006f133d

shippable.yml is:

```
language: scala

scala:
  - 2.11.0

before_script:
  - mkdir -p shippable/testresults
  - ln -s ../target/test-reports shippable/testresults
```

sample project link is: https://github.com/akskas/sample_scala/tree/test-normal

Please provide some more context about your shippable.yml file, if you are still having this issue.
You can follow the progress of this issue here: GITHUB: Shippable/support/issues/2409

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11681250)

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩I have added the code that could change over the time. Other link pages won't change.

Comment: @akskas I believe the reason that it's working for you isn't because of the symlink but rather because you are writing to the shippable/testresults directory in your sbt file. If you remove that from the build you'll see the same results as noted by David. I need to test this out but I believe this problem with the symlink is that you need to only create the `shippable` directory (that is, just the parent directory) for the symlink in the next line to work correctly.

Comment: With regards to my last comment, I couldn't get the symlink to work in such a way that the tests were found. In the end, I simply moved the directory to where shippable expected to find it (`shippable/testresults`) and had success.